# PHP Change array key to its value

Tags: php, arrays

This is abit of an odd request I think, but I really can't figure out how to do it :((

I have an array like this:

```
$oldArray = array([0]=>'str1', [1]=>'str2', [2]=>'str3'...);
[edit:] $oldArray = explode(',',$_POST['something']); // a string from an ajax call
```

But I want to "rejig it" (Sorry, not very technical term there) to this:

```
$newArray = array('str1' => array(), 'str2'=>array(), 'str3'=>array() ... );
[edit:] What I'm actually trying to do is
        $_SESSION['bish']['bash'][$newArrayKEY]['bosh'] = somethingElse;
```

I really hope this is enough information to enable you guys to help me

Many thanks
Gem

Comment: I should of said, the $oldKey is from an explode

Comment: really it is a strange question. Both are same numerical indexing array. Is there any difference? where do you use this in your application

Comment: `print_r` the new array and you will see that it's the same as the old one. I can't understand where is the difference?

Comment: I'll edit the question so it might make more sense .. Thank you

Comment: print_r(array_values($oldArray));

Comment: I am confused - you need multidimensional array where keys will be old array values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$newArray = array_combine(
    $oldArray,
    $oldArray
);
```

will do what you're asking, but I'm not really sure you understand about array keys

All arrays have a key: the default is a simple enumerated key, which is what you have in your original array

effectively you're asking to create

```
$newArray = array('str1' => 'str1', 'str2' => 'str2', 'str3' => 'str3' ... );
```

**EDIT**

With your edit to the question:

```
$newArray = array_fill_keys(
    $oldArray,
    array()
);
```

Though I'm confused by what you're trying to achieve with $_SESSION

Comment: me too, but that answered my question so I thank you :) I'm getting myself very lost ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$newArray = new array();
foreach($oldArray as $key = $value){
    $newArray[] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$newArray = array_values($oldArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not entirely understand what you want to do. There aren't any real difference between your $oldArray and $newArray. It's just two ways of displaying the same array. str1, str2, str3 are the values of your array.

If you try to say you want to move your values to the "key" of the array, take a look at Marks answer, if not, try to explain a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Is `array_values($array)` the function you are looking for?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

Answer (score 0):

`array(0 => 'str1', 1 => 'str2', ..);` is similar with `array('str1', 'str2', ..);`

But this `array([0]=>'str1', [1]=>'str2', [2]=>'str3'...);` that is invalid *array*.

Answer (score 0):

try this simple array function

```
$oldArray = array([0]=>'str1', [1]=>'str2', [2]=>'str3'...);
$array_values = array_values($oldArray);`
```